# Portal Style & Theme

Tags: sap-enterprise-portal

I have integrated SRM 5.0 into Portal. Most of the iviews are IAC i.e., all are ITS based services.

The issue is that the Portal Theme does not get reflected on these services after integration.

When a BSP or Webdynpro is integrated then the application reflects the Portal Theme when executed from Portal but the ITS services are not getting this.

I tried using SE80 and editing EBPApplication.css. In BBPGLOBAL i changed all color attributes to custom colour but no effect.

Whch property should i change to remove the blue colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireFox and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to determine the location of CSS values and  test them online.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ITS Theme generator for your corresponding Portal theme.